# cant run rails app with ngin x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am trying to deploy my rails app with nginx but i am getting two config files

```
1.The one installed globally by my OS's package manager (/usr/sbin/nginx). This uses /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as configuration file by default.

2.The one installed by Phusion Passenger (/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx). This uses /opt/nginx   /conf/nginx.conf as configuration file by default.
```

i really didn't understand what to do now while i have configured my app with 2nd one. how maki it responsive and turn down first one?

Comment: You need to change your init script to start the second version. Please specify your operating system distribution and version.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the nginx telling which configuration to pick.

```
/usr/bin/nginx -t -c ~/mynginx.conf -g "pid /var/run/nginx.pid; worker_processes 2;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [the official Debian or Ubuntu packages for Phusion Passenger](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/09/11/debian-and-ubuntu-packages-for-phusion-passenger/), released 3 days ago. Those packages will install an Nginx with Phusion Passesenger support into /usr/bin/nginx. Those packages even reuse all the operating system files like /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.